# Is g++11 slower than g++9?

Tags: 22.04, performance, g++

Recently I have upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and ran into some problems. I have noticed `g++11` in my computer compiles codes so slowly, even for simple codes, while `g++9` in Ubuntu 20.04 had a much better performance. I wished to ask whether `g++11` is naturally slower than `g++9`, or something else is causing *3 slower performance?

Comment: If you can compare 20.04 and 22.04 on similar hardware you can use the `time` command during compile and [edit] your question by adding some statistics.

Comment: Most probably, yes, given the added features GCC11 has been given. That's a good thing, not a bad one. Split your work in different source files and headers and use a Makefile. It's the best way to keep compilation time low.

Comment: "New version" isn't always automatically the same as "better speed", but more likely  "more options".